# Cannot resolve symbols by ReexportsGenerator in LLVM ORC JIT

Tags: llvm

I'm not good in LLVM so please forgive me wrong termins. There is an issue with `JIT session error: Symbols not found` when trying "lookup" functions from one module which depends on functions from another module. So there are two LLJIT instances:

```cpp
llvm::orc::JITDylib &JD = JIT2->getMainJITDylib();
llvm::orc::JITDylib &SourceJD = JIT1->getMainJITDylib();
```

I wanted utilize [ReexportsGenerator](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/81896f88cef4cfe1cf982250601a0c954344e1e8/llvm/lib/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Core.cpp#L598) as it sounds applicable for my problem (see [addGenerator](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1orc_1_1JITDylib.html#ae89dfebe97fc65907c1b9194aafe1ade)), however the following generator approach doesn't work

```cpp
auto gen = std::make_unique<ReexportsGenerator>(JIT1->getMainJITDylib(),
                                                llvm::orc::JITDylibLookupFlags::MatchAllSymbols);
JIT2->getMainJITDylib().addGenerator(std::move(gen));
```

So when I tried go deeper to the generator's implementation, I've found that `lookupFlags` cannot match desired symbols while `lookup` return an address with no exceptions:

```cpp
llvm::StringRef symName("my_symbol_name");
llvm::orc::SymbolStringPool pool;
llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr symNamePtr = pool.intern(symName);

// Try just lookup the symbol
auto addr = JIT1->lookup(symName);
if (auto E = addr.takeError()) {
    throw E;
}
uint64_t fun_addr = addr->getValue();  // contains correct value so I'm sure that JIT1 has my symbol
```

But number of matches from `lookupFlags` is `0`:

```cpp
// Try symbols resolving
llvm::orc::SymbolLookupSet LookupSet;
LookupSet.add(symNamePtr, llvm::orc::SymbolLookupFlags::WeaklyReferencedSymbol);

auto Flags = JD.getExecutionSession().lookupFlags(
            llvm::orc::LookupKind::DLSym,
            {{&SourceJD, llvm::orc::JITDylibLookupFlags::MatchAllSymbols}},
            LookupSet);
if (auto E = Flags.takeError()) {
    throw E;
}
std::cout << "Flags.size() " << (*Flags).size() << std::endl;
```

My question is, what I have not considered while applied such symbol resolving approach? I'm confused why `lookup` is able to find the symbol while `lookupFlags` not.

Answer (score 0):

> So there are two LLJIT instances...

`ReexportsGenerator` only handles re-exports within a single `LLJIT` instance.

I'll add some comments to `ReexportsGenerator` to clarify this.

```cpp
llvm::StringRef symName("my_symbol_name");
llvm::orc::SymbolStringPool pool;
llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr symNamePtr = pool.intern(symName);
...
```

Lookup within an `LLJIT` instance must use strings interned on that `LLJIT` instance's `SymbolStringPool` (since the uniqued strings will be compared by address and different pools will have different addresses for the same string).

Use of different symbol string pools is the reason `lookupFlags` failed, and `LLJIT::lookup` succeeded (the latter takes a plain string and interns it for you so it ends up in the right pool).

To intern a string on the `LLJIT` instance's pool you can use `JIT.getExecutionSession().intern(<string>)`, however if you are looking things up based on their C or LLVM IR name you should use `LLJIT::mangleAndIntern` instead: it handles both linker-level mangling and interning (on Linux linker-level mangling is a no-op, but on Darwin and Windows it actually changes the string, so using `mangleAndIntern` keeps your code portable).

E.g. to look up the flags for an IR level symbol "foo" in a portable way you'd write:

```cpp
llvm::orc::SymbolLookupSet LookupSet;
LookupSet.add(JIT1->mangleAndIntern("foo"),
              llvm::orc::SymbolLookupFlags::WeaklyReferencedSymbol);
auto Flags =
    JIT1->getExecutionSession().lookupFlags(
        llvm::orc::LookupKind::DLSym,
        {{&SourceJD, llvm::orc::JITDylibLookupFlags::MatchAllSymbols}},
        LookupSet);
...
```

As for `ReexportsGenerator`: We could add a new cross-JIT reexports utility, but have not found a use-case for this yet: Generally if you have references between JIT'd symbols then you want all of those symbols to defined in the same `LLJIT` instance (possibly in multiple JITDylibs). Placing all JIT'd symbols in the one instance gives `LLJIT` a global view of the code it's managing and makes it possible to handle circular dependencies between JIT'd code. Circular dependencies that cross JIT boundaries are not supported.